# Why does installing Tensorflow with conda ruin matplotlib?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, anaconda, conda

Starting from a new anaconda environment, it looks like this (summarized, not a full paste):

```
[myenv]$ python
Python 3.8.8 ...
>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>

[myenv]$ conda install tensorflow-gpu
...

[myenv]$ python
>> import tensorflow
>> tensorflow.__version__
'2.4.1'
>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
>>

[myenv]$ conda install matplotlib
...

[myenv]% python
>> import tensorflow
>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
<tons of traceback>
RunTimeError: the sip module implements API v12.0 to v12.4 but the PyQt5.core module requires API v12.5
```

How can I have tensorflow and matplotlib at the same time?

Comment: What is your channel setup? Maybe include `conda info` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the complete traceback? Based on the Error you posted, it seems like its a dependency issue on the sip module. I'll recommend using you own virtualenv instead of anacondas.

FOR CREATING YOUR OWN VIRTUALENV:
open terminal
go to the directory you want your project to be
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate (for linux or mac)
pip install tensorflow
pip install matplotlib
pip install <whatever library you want>

Comment: I'm kind of stuck with anaconda since I'm offline and acquire packages from an anaconda mirror.  Can't just go out to the internet.

Comment: I see, try importing this module before matplotlib...
**import PyQt5**
You can also try **conda upgrade sip**, if the import does not work